# What are the restrictions on preparing spells following a long rest?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, rests

For spell casting classes like clerics, druids and wizards they can change their prepared spells following a long rest. Does this have to be immediately following a long rest with nothing in between or could a character cast some spells first?

For example, a wizard might cast mage armor on themselves following a long rest, but then prepare a new set of spells not including mage armor.

Also, are you restricted to preparing new spells only once per long rest? Or could a spell caster prepare spells, cast one or more of then, then prepare a new spell list?

Comment: There's a question on this from before, so I think this [is a duplicate of that](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/91568/22566).

Answer (score 1):

**The wording is not "following a long rest", its "when you finish a long rest".**

"Finishing a long rest" is that moment in time when the long rest ends - not any time before or after. You cannot cast a spell in between finishing a long rest and changing your list of prepared spells.

See [Cleric](https://www.dndbeyond.com/characters/classes/cleric#ClassFeatures), [Druid](https://www.dndbeyond.com/characters/classes/druid#ClassFeatures) and [Wizard](https://www.dndbeyond.com/characters/classes/wizard#ClassFeatures).